# condition inside template.php (if logged_in/logged_out and else)

Tags: hooks, database

Is it possible to perform condition inside template.php (if logged_in, do these...else do that/ do nothing)?

I am a front-end developer, and as a front-end developer, i like my code clean. So i'm cleaning up my drupal html source code output.

I found some modules out there, that help a lot, and one of then is HTML5 Tools and Metatag (thank you for the team developers). But even with those great tools, i still having the "Drupal.settings" in my html output.

Ocasionally, i found that i can remove the "Drupal.settings" from the html with the hook_js_alter :

> function MYTHEME_js_alter (&$js) {   unset($js['settings']); }

But the problem is: my logged in users still needing this "Drupal.settings" because some modules use it. So that's why i'm asking if there is a way to perform **condition inside template.php** to logged_in/logged_out users.

THank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out. [Drupal user login - How to tell if a Drupal user is logged in (authenticated)](http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/theme-test-drupal-user-logged-in-authenticated)

You can also use the utility variable [**$logged_in**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes%21bartik%21templates%21page.tpl.php/7): Returns TRUE if the user is registered and signed in.

**Updated answer.**

In **template.php**, you can use `global $user;` to check and see if someone is logged in.

```
global $user;    
if (isset($user->roles[1])) {
  //Put code here.
}
```

Checking against Devel, you can see that `$user->roles[1]` means it's an anonymous user.
[image: Output from Devel]

Comment: It does NOT work with in "template.php". It only work for page.tpl.php

Comment: This should work for ya. If roles[1] is set, it means they're anonymous.

Comment: By the way, you have a new fan (lol) ;)